# Are there any pre-20th century sci-fi novels / short stories about virtual reality?

Tags: history-of

While I'm aware that virtual reality fiction has been increasingly popular since the mid-20th century, I'm wondering if this topic / genre was engaged with in earlier sci-fi / fantasy fiction. Given that such great fiction was being written in late 19th century (e.g. by H.G. Wells), I thought that perhaps there might be some pre-20th century contributions to this genre.

Of course, the term 'virtual reality' is open to interpretation. I'm interested in all sorts ... even if more 'philosophical' (e.g. reality as a product of Mind) rather than hard science (associated with computer technology). As such, I'm not restricting concern with 'virtual reality' to how it's typically understood in contemporary times.

Comment: According to the [accepted answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85485/which-sci-fi-work-introduced-the-idea-of-virtual-reality/85523#85523) to the question [Which Sci-Fi work introduced the idea of "Virtual Reality"?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85485/which-sci-fi-work-introduced-the-idea-of-virtual-reality), the earliest sci-fi story about virtual reality was the 1930 novelette ["City of the Living Dead"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?70726) by Laurence Manning and Fletcher Pratt.

Comment: @Simon I'm afraid your question is too broad as it stands now. What about stories that take place in a dream, do they count?

Comment: Would Plato's Cave count?